# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (2048) must match the size of tensor b (2) at non-singleton dimension 0

Tags: neural-network, classification, loss-function, tabular, imbalanced-data

I'm working on a highly imbalanced dataset for a tabular binary classification task. I'm using pytorch and skorch to build my DNN with output_dim = 1. Assigning class weights is better than upsampling based on the nature of my dataset. However, when I run:

```
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight

class_weight = compute_class_weight(class_weight = 'balanced', classes = np.unique(y_train), y = y_train)


net = NeuralNetBinaryClassifier(
    DNN,
    lr = 0.001,
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD,
    criterion = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(),
    train_split = predefined_split(val_data),
    max_epochs = 1000,
    batch_size = 2048,
    criterion__weight = class_weight,
    callbacks=[
    (skorch.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience = 5, threshold = 1e-3))
    ]
)

net.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

a RuntimeError pops up:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 1
----> 1 net.fit(X_train, y_train)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skorch\classifier.py:348, in NeuralNetBinaryClassifier.fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    337 """See ``NeuralNet.fit``.
    338 
    339 In contrast to ``NeuralNet.fit``, ``y`` is non-optional to
   (...)
    343 
    344 """
    345 # pylint: disable=useless-super-delegation
    346 # this is actually a pylint bug:
    347 # https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1085
--> 348 return super().fit(X, y, **fit_params)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skorch\net.py:1319, in NeuralNet.fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
   1316 if not self.warm_start or not self.initialized_:
   1317     self.initialize()
-> 1319 self.partial_fit(X, y, **fit_params)
   1320 return self

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skorch\net.py:1278, in NeuralNet.partial_fit(self, X, y, classes, **fit_params)
   1276 self.notify('on_train_begin', X=X, y=y)
   1277 try:
-> 1278     self.fit_loop(X, y, **fit_params)
   1279 except KeyboardInterrupt:
   1280     pass

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skorch\net.py:1190, in NeuralNet.fit_loop(self, X, y, epochs, **fit_params)
   1187 for _ in range(epochs):
   1188     self.notify('on_epoch_begin', **on_epoch_kwargs)
-> 1190     self.run_single_epoch(iterator_train, training=True, prefix="train",
   1191                           step_fn=self.train_step, **fit_params)
   1193     self.run_single_epoch(iterator_valid, training=False, prefix="valid",
   1194                           step_fn=self.validation_step, **fit_params)
   1196     self.notify("on_epoch_end", **on_epoch_kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skorch\net.py:1226, in NeuralNet.run_single_epoch(self, iterator, training, prefix, step_fn, **fit_params)
   1224 for batch in iterator:
   1225     self.notify("on_batch_begin", batch=batch, training=training)
-> 1226     step = step_fn(batch, **fit_params)
   1227     self.history.record_batch(prefix + "_loss", step["loss"].item())
   1228     batch_size = (get_len(batch[0]) if isinstance(batch, (tuple, list))
   1229                   else get_len(batch))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skorch\net.py:1105, in NeuralNet.train_step(self, batch, **fit_params)
   1097     self.notify(
   1098         'on_grad_computed',
   1099         named_parameters=TeeGenerator(self.get_all_learnable_params()),
   1100         batch=batch,
   1101         training=True,
   1102     )
   1103     return step['loss']
-> 1105 self._step_optimizer(step_fn)
   1106 return step_accumulator.get_step()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skorch\net.py:1060, in NeuralNet._step_optimizer(self, step_fn)
   1058     optimizer.step()
   1059 else:
-> 1060     optimizer.step(step_fn)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\optimizer.py:113, in Optimizer._hook_for_profile.<locals>.profile_hook_step.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    111 profile_name = "Optimizer.step#{}.step".format(obj.__class__.__name__)
    112 with torch.autograd.profiler.record_function(profile_name):
--> 113     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\grad_mode.py:27, in _DecoratorContextManager.__call__.<locals>.decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
     24 @functools.wraps(func)
     25 def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
     26     with self.clone():
---> 27         return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\sgd.py:125, in SGD.step(self, closure)
    123 if closure is not None:
    124     with torch.enable_grad():
--> 125         loss = closure()
    127 for group in self.param_groups:
    128     params_with_grad = []

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skorch\net.py:1094, in NeuralNet.train_step.<locals>.step_fn()
   1092 def step_fn():
   1093     self._zero_grad_optimizer()
-> 1094     step = self.train_step_single(batch, **fit_params)
   1095     step_accumulator.store_step(step)
   1097     self.notify(
   1098         'on_grad_computed',
   1099         named_parameters=TeeGenerator(self.get_all_learnable_params()),
   1100         batch=batch,
   1101         training=True,
   1102     )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skorch\net.py:994, in NeuralNet.train_step_single(self, batch, **fit_params)
    992 Xi, yi = unpack_data(batch)
    993 y_pred = self.infer(Xi, **fit_params)
--> 994 loss = self.get_loss(y_pred, yi, X=Xi, training=True)
    995 loss.backward()
    996 return {
    997     'loss': loss,
    998     'y_pred': y_pred,
    999 }

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skorch\net.py:1665, in NeuralNet.get_loss(self, y_pred, y_true, X, training)
   1636 """Return the loss for this batch.
   1637 
   1638 Parameters
   (...)
   1662 
   1663 """
   1664 y_true = to_tensor(y_true, device=self.device)
-> 1665 return self.criterion_(y_pred, y_true)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1130, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1126 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1127 # this function, and just call forward.
   1128 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:714, in BCEWithLogitsLoss.forward(self, input, target)
    713 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 714     return F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target,
    715                                               self.weight,
    716                                               pos_weight=self.pos_weight,
    717                                               reduction=self.reduction)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:3150, in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce, reduction, pos_weight)
   3147 if not (target.size() == input.size()):
   3148     raise ValueError("Target size ({}) must be the same as input size ({})".format(target.size(), input.size()))
-> 3150 return torch.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, pos_weight, reduction_enum)

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (2048) must match the size of tensor b (2) at non-singleton dimension 0
```

I guess it has something to do with my loss fn. Tensor 'a' must be a batch, but I don't know where tensor 'b' comes from. How do I check or what am I doing wrong?

Also, I tried running the network without class weights and this error didn't show up.